# How to launch programs into background within a bash for loop

Tags: bash

Following script fragment launches the shell script sqoopToHdfs.sh once for each entry in tabs, but sequentially:

```
tabs="contracts employees resources"
for t in $tabs; do /shared/sqoopToHdfs.sh $t >$t.out 2>&1 ; done
```

But the following attempt to launch all of those in parallel does *not* work:

```
for t in $tabs; do /shared/sqoopToHdfs.sh $t >$t.out 2>&1 **&**; done
```

So what is correct syntax to launch in background that is compatible with the for loop (or to achieve the same effect) ?

Comment: The title of the 'possible duplicate' would not be useful in finding answer to my question - even if the root issue were the same.

Comment: And that's okay. That's why we handled it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding an `&` at the end

```
for t in $tabs; do /shared/sqoopToHdfs.sh $t >$t.out 2>&1 & done
```

Im not sure how long you want these to run for but they will all be tied to the terminal, you can disown the process after its been made like this to keep them alive if you close that teminal

`disown PID`

Comment: How would I insert the (capture PID, disown PID) into the one liner?

Comment: There were several answers v similar to each other. I will award this one because the "disown" is kind of important and i had not considered it before.

Comment: disown can also prefix a command so should be able to slot in just after the `do`

Answer (score 2):

Lose the `;`

```
for t in $tabs; do /shared/sqoopToHdfs.sh $t >$t.out 2>&1 & done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write it on a single line: (no semicolon after the ampersand):

```
for t in $tabs; do /shared/sqoopToHdfs.sh $t > $t.out 2>&1 & done
```

Btw, you should use more robust syntax, and an array:

```
tabs=( contracts employees resources)
for t in "${tabs[@]}"; do /shared/sqoopToHdfs.sh "$t" > "$t.out" 2>&1 & done
```

or (it's exactly the same):

```
tabs=( contracts employees resources)
for t in "${tabs[@]}"; do
    /shared/sqoopToHdfs.sh "$t" > "$t.out" 2>&1 &
done
```

(and with this form, you'd never've had a problem!)

Answer (score 1):

how about :

```
 pins=""
 for t in $tabs; do 
    nohup /shared/sqoopToHdfs.sh $t >$t.out 2>&1 & 
    pins="$!,$pins"
 done
```